# Add columns to result

Tags: integration, pentaho, kettle

i use pentaho data integration.
I have three columns A,B,C i want to use C in "Input Table" Transformation for a select to another database.
so i have added "Select Value"  before "Input Table" so my sql work fine, and that return me only one column : 'D'

But now i have two stream A,B,C and another D.

I havn't primary key in my second stream so how can i merge all columns,
My final result will be A,B,C,D

I have tried with "Merge join" but not working because i havn't primary key

ps: two stream retun me the same number of rows

Comment: can't understand your issue.

Comment: did you want the number of raws is same as in ABC or in D stream.? also ABC streams row number 5 should be attached with row number 5 of D stream?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Joins rows" and do not select any fields, this will add the column D on the main flow.

Comment: This will give cartesian product means number of rows is multiplication of number of input rows.